# Existence of primitive for continuous function on an open interval $(a,b)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Show that any continuous function on an open interval has a primitive on that interval.

**My approach:** This result is elementary if we replace open interval by closed interval.

**Fact:** Indeed, if the function $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ then the function $F:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $x\mapsto \int_{a}^{x}f(t)dt$  is continuous on $[a,b]$ and $F'(x)=f(x)$ on $[a,b]$.

Assume that our function $f(x)$ is continuous on $(0,1)$. For each $\delta\in (0,1/2)$ we know that $[\delta,1-\delta]\subset (0,1)$ and $f(x)$ is continuous on $[\delta,1-\delta]$. Hence by fact it has a primitive $F_{\delta}:[\delta,1-\delta]\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $F_{\delta}$ is continuous on $[\delta,1-\delta]$ and $F'_{\delta}(x)=f(x)$ on $[\delta,1-\delta]$.

For each $x\in (0,1)$ there are infinitely many $\delta>0$ such that $x\in (\delta,1-\delta)$. So by Axiom of Choice for each $x\in (0,1)$ we can assign $\delta(x)>0$ such that $x\in (\delta(x),1-\delta(x))$.

Thus define the function $F:(0,1)\to \mathbb{R}$ by $x\mapsto F_{\delta(x)}(x)$ and this function has all desired properties.

I was wondering is this solution correct?
At least I cannot find any mistakes in my reasoning.

So I'd be vert grateful if you can take a look and check it.

**EDIT:** Suppose that $f$ is continuous on $(0,1)$. Take $r>0$ such that $[r,1-r]\subset (0,1)$ and $f$ being continuous on $[r,1-r]$ has a primitive say $G(t)$, i.e. $G(t)$ is continuous on $[r,1-r]$ and $G'(t)=f(t)$ on $[r,1-r]$.

For any $x\in (0,1)$ we assign $\delta_x>0$ such that $x\in (\delta_x,1-\delta_x)$. This can be done by Axiom of Choice.

On each such closed interval $[\delta_x,1-\delta_x]$ the function $f$ has a primitive $\hat{F}_{\delta_x}$. We note that $\hat{F}_{\delta_x}-G\equiv c_x$ on $[\alpha,1-\alpha]$, where $\alpha=\max\{r,\delta_x\}$ and $c_x$ is a constant but it "depends" on $x$.

Define a function $F_{\delta_x}:[\delta_x,1-\delta_x]\to \mathbb{R}$ by $F_{\delta_x}:=\hat{F}_{\delta_x}-c_x$.

I guess our primitive is gonna be the function $P:(0,1)\to \mathbb{R}$ defines as $P(x):=F_{\delta_x}(x)$. However, I have some technical issues to prove that it continuous on $(0,1)$ and its derivative is $f$ for all $x\in (0,1)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your construction is almost there, but not quite. It is not yet certain that $F$ is indeed the primitive of $f$.

---

For example, take $f(x)=1$ on $[0,1]$.

Then, take $$F_{\delta(x)} = \begin{cases}x\mapsto x& x\geq \frac12\\ x\mapsto x+1&x<\frac12\end{cases}$$

If your choice of $F_{\delta(x)}$ is the one described above, then $F$ is not continuous at $x=\frac12$, and so it is not differentiable on $(0,1)$, and it is not the primitive of $f$.

---

You need some more work in actually selecting $F_{\delta(x)}$. Not a lot more, you just need to make sure all the primitives "line up", which you can do since you have a constant factor to play around with.

---

**Edit**:

Your new solution's construction looks better, and avoids the problem I describe above. Now, as you say, all you need is to prove that $P$ is continuous.

But this is simple, because think about what you created by your new construction.

Take, for example, any two values $x_1, x_2\in(0,1)$. Then there exists some $\delta_1, \delta_2$ such that $x_i\in(\delta_i, 1-\delta_i)$ for $i=1,2$. Without loss of generality, let's assume $\delta_1<\delta_2$.

Then, it should be simple to see that $F_{\delta_1}|_{(\delta_2, 1-\delta_2)} \equiv F_{\delta_2}$, that is, the two functions are **identical**. You can see that because

1. both functions are primitives of the same function, which means they may only differ by a constant
2. the two functions match on at least one point (by construction).

This means that on any interval $(\delta, 1-\delta)$, the function $P$ is identically equal to the function $F_{(\delta, 1-\delta)}$, and so in particular, that means $P$ is continuous at all points of $(0,1)$.

Comment: I am really confused. To be honest I do not see any connection of your example with my reasoning yet. I am defining my function $F:(0,1)\to \mathbb{R}$ in the following way: $F(x):=F_{\delta(x)}(x)$ for each $x\in (0,1)$. I guess that $F(x)$ is continuous because it is determined in terms of $F_{\delta}(x)$ which is continuous. What is wrong with this reasoning?

Comment: @ZFR I provide an example where the function $x\mapsto F_{\delta(x)}(x)$ is not continuous. That's what my whole answer is about.

Comment: I think that I got your example but let me illustrate more expanded version: firstly it is better to take the function $f:(0,1)\to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x)=1$. 

For each $x\in (0,1/2)$ we can find $\delta(x)>0$ such that $x\in (\delta(x),1-\delta(x))$ and $f$ being continuous on $[\delta(x),1-\delta(x)]$ it has a primitive $F_{\delta(x)}$ on $[\delta(x),1-\delta(x)]$. And we сan take $F_{\delta(x)}:[\delta(x),1-\delta(x)]\to \mathbb{R}$ which is defined by $F_{\delta(x)}(t)=t$.

Comment: The same we can do when $x\in [1/2,1)$ but taking $F_{\delta(x)}:[\delta(x),1-\delta(x)]\to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $F_{\delta(x)}(t)=t+1.$ Then by my reasoning we obtain function $F$ on $(0,1)$ defined by $x\mapsto x$ for $x\in (0,1/2)$ and $x\mapsto x+1$ for $x\in [1/2,1)$ which is not continuous at $1/2$. Am I right?

Comment: @ZFR Yes, my point is that your construction does not guarantee you will not get something like you describe.

Comment: Please take a look at my edit.

Comment: Maybe now you can show the correct solution?

Comment: @ZFR See my edit.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will take a look at this. I see you have shown that $P$ is continuous on $(0,1)$ and that is good. But what about $P'(x)=f(x)$ on $(0,1)$?

Comment: Can you show this also, please?

Comment: @ZFR The method should be very similar to the one showing continuity.

Comment: Thank you so much! After some thoughts I realized that one can consider a function $F:(0,1)\to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $F(x)=\int_{1/2}^{x}f(t)dt$. Is this assumption correct?

Comment: @ZFR Sure, if you already know what definite integrals are, but I like your original approach more, it feels neater because it assumes less :)

Answer (score 0):

First, following the completeness of $\mathbb{R}$, we can always find some $r\in(a,b)$. Then for any $x\in(a,b)$, the closed interval $[x,r]$ or $[r,x]$ are subset of $(a,b)$, thus $f$ is continuous on them and we can define
$$\mathcal{F}(x)=\int_{r}^{x}f(t)\mathrm{d} t$$
with the identity $\int_{x}^{r}f(t)\mathrm{d} t=-\int_{r}^{x}f(t)\mathrm{d} t$, this function is defined for all $x\in(a,b)$. Now we prove it is continuous on $(a,b)$ and $\mathcal{F}'(x)=f(x)$:

\begin{align*}
 &\mathcal{F}(x+h)-\mathcal{F}(x)=\int_{r}^{x+h}f(t)\mathrm{d} t-\int_{r}^{x}f(t)\mathrm{d} t\\
 =&\int_{r}^{x}f(t)\mathrm{d} t+\int_{x}^{x+h}f(t)\mathrm{d} t-\int_{r}^{x}f(t)\mathrm{d} t\\
 =&\int_{x}^{x+h}f(t)\mathrm{d} t
\end{align*}
Let $\Delta(t)=f(x)-f(t)\Rightarrow f(t)=f(x)-\Delta(t)$. Since $f$ is continuous on $(a,b)$, we claim that
$$\lim_{t\to x}f(t)=f(x)\Rightarrow\lim_{t\to x}\Delta(t)=\lim_{t\to x}\left(f(x)-f(t)\right)=0$$
Therefore
\begin{align*}
 &\int_{x}^{x+h}f(t)\mathrm{d} t=\int_{x}^{x+h}\left(f(x)-\Delta(t)\right)\mathrm{d} t\\
 =&\int_{x}^{x+h}f(x)\mathrm{d} t-\int_{x}^{x+h}\Delta(t)\mathrm{d} t\\
 =&f(x)\cdot h-\int_{x}^{x+h}\Delta(t)\mathrm{d} t
\end{align*}

Since $t\in[x,x+h]$, we have
$$h\to 0\Rightarrow f(x+h)\to f(x)\Rightarrow f(t)\to f(x)\Rightarrow \Delta(t)\to 0$$

which means $\Delta(t)$ is an infinitesimal of $h$, so we write

$$\mathcal{F}(x+h)-\mathcal{F}(x)=\int_{x}^{x+h}f(t)\mathrm{d} t=f(x)\cdot h-\alpha(h)\cdot h$$

This simultaneously indicates that (1) as $h\to 0$, $\mathcal{F}(x+h)-\mathcal{F}(x)\to 0$, so $\mathcal{F}(x)$ is continuous at $x$ (hence continuous on $(a,b)$, even though may not be uniformly continuous); (2) $\mathcal{F}'(x)=f(x)$ because this is exactly the definition of derivative.

It is quite obvious that select a different $r_{1}$ results in a primitive that differs from this one by the constant $\int_{r}^{r_{1}}f(t)\mathrm{d}t$